# Remove focus on showing devexpress popup

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, devexpress

I use `Devexpress` UserControls in my ASP.Net Project for displaying, editing, and deleting rows of data.

On one of my pages, I have two controls, a `DevExpress grid` and an `ASP.Net button`. When I want to edit a row, I click on the edit button of that row, whereupon a popup showing detail of that row is displayed. I can edit these details and then take some action. Tthis popup has buttons *Cancel* and *Save*, and when I press *Enter* key I want the *Save* action to be invoked. However, currently, when I press the *Enter* key, it is getting directed to the main page and not the dialog?

Does anyone know how I can get the *Enter* key to activate the *Save* action on the dialog instead?

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Review the following examples to learn more on how to handle document events and respond to a particular end-user action:

[E352](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E352)

[E3845](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E3845)